# POJO classes in Spring

Tags: java, spring

I wanted to ask a question based on the [introduction to Spring Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/overview.html#:%7E:text=Spring%20enables%20you%20to%20build%20applications%20from%20%E2%80%9Cplain%20old%20Java%20objects%E2%80%9D%20(POJOs)%20and%20to%20apply%20enterprise%20services%20non%2Dinvasively%20to%20POJOs.) statement that says

> Spring enables you to build applications from “plain old Java objects” (POJOs) and to apply enterprise services non-invasively to POJOs.

Does the POJO mentioned here mean any simple Java class? Would a Java class in Spring that extends or implements another class which I created or that was provided by the Java standard library make it not a POJO anymore?

Comment: The desciption covers it imho. Anything that doesn't use any enterprisey stuff (like the EJB stuff from ye old) is a POJO.

Comment: @M.Deinum so a Java class would still be considered a POJO if it extends or inherits another class, as long as it doesnt come from an external source?

Comment: No as long as it doesn't use any enterprise stuff. Like Message Driven Beans, EJB, etc. etc.

Comment: ok I understand, thank you for your help

Comment: @myuh236: yes, though the *exact* definition of "external source" is somewhat vague. As long as the class doesn't extend or implement any interfaces/classes from some framework or another it can be considered a POJO.

Comment: got it, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Don't focus too much on the semantics of what a POJO is.  In this context they are referring more to JavaBeans, which...

> must be serializable, have a zero-argument constructor, and allow access to properties using getter and setter methods.

See the wiki entry for a POJO: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_old_Java_object

In this context, they are speaking more specifically about JavaBeans: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaBeans